# How to show code with octopress

Tags: jekyll, liquid, octopress

I want to display on my site built with Octopress the following text:

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ item[0] }}/">{{ item[0] | capitalize }}</a> [ {{ item[1].size }} ]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I inserted { % raw %} before and respectively {% endraw ½} after my text.

```
{% raw %}
<ul>
{% for item in site.categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ item[0] }}/">{{ item[0] | capitalize }}</a> [ {{ item[1].size }} ]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endraw ½}
```

The result is:

```
{% for item in site.categories %}
```

- List item
  {{ item[0] | capitalize }} [ {{ item[1].size }} ]
  {% endfor %}

I was expected:

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ item[0] }}/">{{ item[0] | capitalize }}</a> [ {{ item[1].size }} ]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you reword this? It is not clear what you are expecting to see, or what you are trying to do. There are (I'm assuming) mistakes in the `raw` tags.

Comment: I reworded my text. Hope it's better

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches your can take, I am assuming you are trying to put this content in a markdown file and use the kramdown markdown processor in Jekyll.

### Using the 'Raw' tag and codeblocks

```
{% raw %}

~~~
<ul>
{% for item in site.categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ item[0] }}/">{{ item[0] | capitalize }}</a> [ {{ item[1].size }} ]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
~~~

{% endraw %}
```

The raw tag needs to be used to prevent the liquid tags from being processed, and the fenced code block prevents the HTML from being passed straight through the markdown processor. It will be presented as a code block as above.

### Using 'Raw' and 'Highlight'

If you want the HTML to be highlighted you can use this approach. Unfortunately Pygments does not do highlighting of liquid tags.

```
{% highlight html %}
{% raw %}
<ul>
{% for item in site.categories %}
<li><a href="/categories/{{ item[0] }}/">{{ item[0] | capitalize }}</a> [ {{ item[1].size }} ]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between your first proposition and my approach. For me, that doesn't work. Yes, this is the content of a markdown file and I am using Jekyll and Octopress.

Comment: @Bertaud What markdown processor are you using (It will make a difference)? Did you try copy pasting my example as-is? The difference between the your approach and my first is that mine is using a fenced code block in order to prevent the HTML from also being rendered. Kramdown uses three '~' characters to signify this, some markdown processors use three backticks.